# How do you write this sentence in French? "Don't live in fear of the future, cause I'll always be there."

Tags: grammaire, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

I think it's

> N'aie pas peur du futur, car je serai toujours là.

But *du futur* can be *de l'avenir*. I don't know.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for supplying a suggestion. It's a pretty good start, but you have options for several words.

I would indeed use *avenir* instead of *futur* here. Although *futur* is possible, to me it sounds a little stiff considering the association with grammar terms — whereas this is a more heartfelt sentence.

> N'aie pas peur **de l'avenir**, car je serai toujours là.

Also, while *toujours* can mean *always*, it can also mean *still* in that sentence and with that placement, so you could go for a stronger *pour toujours*.

> N'aie pas peur de l'avenir, car je serai là **pour toujours**.

Or, perhaps too poetically, *à jamais* :

> N'aie pas peur de l'avenir, car je serai là **à jamais**.

Also, if your original sentence does indeed have "cause" instead of "because", then *car* could be a little too high a register. (In Europe, at least, it can be translated *for* and be matched with *à jamais*.)

> N'aie pas peur de l'avenir, **parce que** je serai là pour toujours.

You could also delete *car* altogether; I think this borders on style editing, but it has a nice flow. Feelew writes below that having the causal relation spelled out seems to lose some of the warmth and focus attention on the speaker. That could look like:

> N'aie pas peur de l'avenir ; je serai là pour toujours.

Finally, your English has "Don't live in fear" but the French you supplied says "Don't be afraid", so if you wanted to capture that first meaning you might try:

> **Ne vis pas dans la crainte** de l'avenir, parce que je serai là pour toujours.
>   
> **Ne vis pas dans la peur** de l'avenir, parce que je serai là pour toujours.

As Stéphane points out below, the negation could also be *plus* ("anymore", "no longer"), if this word of comfort is given to someone who has already been living in fear up to this point.

> Ne vis **plus** dans la crainte de l'avenir, car je serai là à jamais.

(P.S. Don't forget, as jlliagre mentions below, that if you're addressing more than one person you would use the *vous* forms: *N'ayez pas* or *Ne vivez pas*. I don't think this sentence is likely to be spoken using the polite *vous*, though, so if it's just one person I'd stick with the *tu* forms.)

---

Mix and match from among all these to get the right tone. :)

Disclaimer: I'm not a native speaker and invite any corrections if people disagree with my reading of the nuances or have better suggestions.

Comment: Tough "en crainte" definitely has some charm, I must say I don't think I've ever heard or read it, and if I did, it wasn't in that type of structure. Also, I think it would be nice to have a variation with an implicit "car" or "parce que" (basically dropping the preposition altogether), it would offer a quicker link between the clauses, flow gracefully, and it is easy for the listener to deduce its hidden presence after being told not to be afraid of something.

Comment: Whoops! I meant "dans la crainte". Agreed about the deleted conjunction option, though I felt that was style editing rather than translation.

Comment: I thought French more than English would tend to drop the conjunction (I'm so embarrassed: mais ou et donc car ni or), so it wouldn't be style editing so much, but I might be wrong. If I were to say something like this to my kids (which of course I wouldn't, BECAUSE I don't know what the fabric of my future is and death might await for me just around the corner), I would definitely not use it in French, though English could easily live with it.

Comment: More on my feel of it: the original version is meant to be reassuring more than to prove the speaker's value. When the French conjunction is not dropped, it feels more like an analytic demonstration and the feeling of warmth is a little gone through the focus being given to the last clause (attention to the speaker) compared to the first (fear, doubt, insecurity of the hearer). Then again, the same feeling could be transmitted WITH the conjunction, but tone would need to be fined-tuned a lot more to avoid any misinterpretation.

Comment: Hmm. Quite interesting. I'm not sure I can pick up on that effect, but I do find that the more imposing presence of *parce que* (compared to *car*) seems to insist on the cause and effect. Also, I think the English sentence is fairly neutral as to whether the "I'll always be there" is incidental or the key reason, though I was trying to avoid too much stress by not suggesting another phrasing that sounds natural to me: "car moi, je serai ..." But I'll make reference to your reading in an edit.

Comment: Your mention of *futur*’s association with grammar made me think of how the OP’s version could be used by overly/inappropriately compassionate French teachers trying to reassure their students as they begin the unit on future tenses: “N'aie pas peur du futur, car je serai toujours là. [Par contre, t’auras bientôt de quoi craindre avec le subjonctif!]”

Comment: The translation might also start with ***N'ayez** pas peur du futur…" depending on who is talking and to whom.

Comment: @PapaPoule lol ! And "...bien que tu aies de quoi craindre avec le subjonctif" for a dose of sadism.

Comment: Ne vis *plus* sounds more likely in French. I gather *anymore* in English has to be left out for being too cumbersome.